# Django REST Framework perform_create: You cannot call `.save()` after accessing `serializer.data`

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I currently have the following viewset:

```
class ArtistProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ArtistProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArtistProfileSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
```

With the following serializers:

```
class SimpleArtistTrackSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ArtistTrack
        fields = (...my fields...)


class ArtistProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owners = UserSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    tracks = SimpleArtistTrackSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = ArtistProfile
        fields = (...my fields...)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
AssertionError: You cannot call `.save()` after accessing `serializer.data`.If you need to access data before committing to the database then inspect 'serializer.validated_data' instead.
```

I don't see where I would be editing the serializer.data object. Is there something I am missing that would cause this edit? How can I resolve this error?

Comment: I rarely needed a method override in the view and when I needed one it often ended up with hacks and copy pastes from the original overridden code. It is usually better to implement stuff on the serializer whenever possible. Isn't it possible to put your stuff to the `create()` method of the serializer?

Comment: I agree that I should re-investigate how I am doing this. However, I still feel like this could be a sign of problem. I took that code straight from DRF's documentation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to call `is_valid` there at all.  When you do an update the serializer is initialized with the model instance (based of the `pk` in the route, e.g `PATCH /artists/{3}/`).  You would call `is_valid()` if you are passing data to the serializer as in:

```
ser = MySerializer(data=request.data) # validate incoming post, etc
ser.is_valid(raise_exceptions=True)
data = ser.validated_data
```

To send additional data to the serializer when saving (e.g. to set a company, or set a user, etc), use an override like this:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(company=self.request.user.company)
```

For more details, I would browse the DRF source code and see what it is doing.  it's very well written and clear.

Your comment indicates another question which is *much* bigger.  You say you want to add additional data to the "join" table between artists and user.  This can be done, but is a whole different topic and you end up manually managing the relationship.  Also, read up on nested writable serializers, it's a big topic and even more manual labor.

Comment: Removing is_valid still produces the same error, however, preventing me from doing what you did in your second example. I do want to add to the join table ultimately, but i need to resolve this issue first, I think. Thank you for your additional comments about the nested writable serializer; I will investigate.

Comment: Writable nested representations are exactly what I need. Thank you for your comment. However, I still feel like the original question could be a sign of problem. I took that code straight from DRF's documentation.

Comment: @KerryRitter Writable nested representations always have to be handled with custom code usually in the serializer's `create()` and/or `update()`: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

Comment: @KerryRitter Glad the answer helped.  Upvote if it actually did.  I'm not sure where the example you have is from, but I copy and pasted one of my many serializers which does this.  If you prefer to have a discussion about it, hop onto `gitter` and go to the DRF group (https://gitter.im/tomchristie/django-rest-framework).  If you really want to do this nested additional data, I have an example but it will take a bit of explaining.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using PyCharm and you were debugging some code, check if you hadn't called `serializer.data` in your debugger "watches". It call `.data` everytime your debugger stop in given context(breakpoint) that given serializer appear, even if you don't call it explicit(`serializer.data`)  in your code.

Answer (score 0):

In the same way that "watches" if you are debugging, try not to inspect (or expand) the `'data'` field of the `serializer` before going through the `save()` line.